# How to prevent re-submit form by reloading page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I submit an form and add some records to my model.

I redirect to the following URI by

```
    format.html { render 'index' }

http://localhost:3000/cart/submit_order?utf8=%E2%9C%93&customer_id=654&book_ids[]=42147&book_ids[]=42148&commit=%E6%96%B0%E5%A2%9E%E8%A8%82%E5%96%AE
```

However, If I reload the page again.

It will submit the data to my model again.

How to prevent this kind of action ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your controller index method, clear the current params hash.  This will effectively reset the form.

params is a hash, so you'll need to use: `params.delete :key`

You didn't show us what form values you're capturing, so you'll have to replace :key with whatever key(s) your form is storing.

Comment: excuse me. did you mean put `params.clear` in index method? but it didn't work.

Comment: it seems not works. `http://localhost:3000/cart/submit_order?utf8=%E2%9C%93&book_ids[]=42157&commit=%E6%96%B0%E5%A2%9E%E8%A8%82%E5%96%AE` after submit my URL is above. then I reload the page it submit again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're sending your form data via GET and not POST, so based on this new information, I suggest changing to a redirect instead...

`format.html { redirect_to { action: 'index' }, notice: 'your flash message here' }`

More information can be found here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html

Comment: `format.html { redirect_to action: "index"  }` works. But loss the `flash`  message `flash[:notice] = "~~~"` . any ideas?